# Elastic search: Two level nested mapping, estimate total number of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have mapping as:

```
"properties": {
  "parents": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "parent_id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "doc_values": false
      },
      "child": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "is_deleted": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "doc_values": false
          },
          "child_id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "doc_values": false
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long",
            "doc_values": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "other_ID": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "doc_values": false
  }
}
```

I have assigned 5 shards (My Elastic search cluster has 7 node) to this index but not sure if that will be sufficient.

> Each Elasticsearch shard is a Lucene index. There is a maximum number
>   of documents you can have in a single Lucene index. As of LUCENE-5843,
>   the limit is 2,147,483,519 (= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 128) documents. You
>   can monitor shard sizes using the _cat/shards api.

Assuming there will be say `x` unique `_ID` and each _IDs will have `y` parents and each parent will have `z` child. what will be total document count in my index?

**Update:**

> To safeguard against ill-defined mappings the number of nested fields
>   that can be defined per index has been limited to 50

Does this means that i can't have more than 50 parents in a _ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real document count you'll see is the number of top-level documents only, not the number of nested ones even though each nested document is a Lucene document under the hood.

So if you are looking for the total number of Lucene documents, if each of the `x` top-level documents has `y` parents and each `parents` element has `z` child elements, then for each top-level document you will have `x * (1 + (y * (1 + z)))` Lucene documents.

Whether it fits or not on your cluster, totally depends on the values of `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: each parent will have unique child i.e. there is no common child among parents. are you sure it will be (y*z). if yes why so?

Comment: actually it's `y * (1 + z)`, but if each parent has a single child (i.e. `z=1`) then it's `y * 2`. Also if you have a single child, you  don't need to use nested for `child`, it's a waste of resource

Comment: I means each parent can have multiple children but there is no common child among parents

Comment: Then if parent A has children 1 + 2 + 3 and parent B has children 4 + 5 + 6, then you have `2 * (1 + 3)` documents, i.e. 2 for the parents and 6 for the children

Comment: can i say it as per _ID it will be total number of parents + total number of children ? i.e. if parent A has 1+2 and parent B has 3+4+5 then it will be 2 (A,B) + 5 (1,2,3,4,5) = 7. can you answer my second question i added?

Comment: 7 is correct + you can add 1 for the top-level document. And the 50 limit is only the number of different nested field definitions in all mappings of a given index, not the number of nested documents.